# SQL Server DateTime and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with the following simple query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Created = '28/02/2013'
```

The issue is the column `CREATED` is a `datetime` datatype, so the query executes fine as long as the timestamp is 0:00:0, if the time stamp is set to say 12:00, then the query does not return a result set.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CAST(Created AS DATE) = '28/02/2013'
```

will fix it, but be careful, it disables indexes

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Created BETWEEN '28/02/2013 00:00' AND '28/02/2013 23:59'
```

And this will use index

Comment: You shouldn't use `BETWEEN` if the time part is important. What happens with values like `'20130228 23:59:59'`, they will get filtered out

Comment: It's just an example, for sure you can specify seconds if needed too

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not specifying the time, so it assumes that you are doing:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Created = '28/02/2013 00:00:00'
```

If you want the whole day, then you need a range of times:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE Created >= '20130228' AND Created < '20130301'
```

Also, please use non ambiguous format for dates (`'YYYYMMDD'`) instead of other formats.

Comment: @DavidB No, I do mean `'YYYYMMDD'` for SQL Server since its not ambiguous on that RDBMS (for DATETIME and DATE datatypes). (Though `'YYYY-MM-DD'` is also not ambiguous for DATE datatype).

Comment: @DavidB: SQL Server's interpretation of "ISO-8601" for `DATETIME` truly is **only** `YYYYMMDD` (**no dashes!**). With the dashes - which would be the "normal" ISO-8601 standard **does not work** for all language settings - it **can** (and will) fail for e.g. "German" or "UK British" (or pretty much any European langauge) language settings...

Answer (score 1):

***If you don't need to consider time:*** try to convert `created` field to `date` and then compare as;

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE convert(date,Created) = '28/02/2013'

--this would be even better with iso date format (not culture specific)
SELECT * FROM users WHERE convert(date,Created) = '20130228' --yyyymmdd format
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the column into date and then compare

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Created, 106) = '28 Feb 2013'
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE convert(varchar(20),a.time_inserted,101)='02/28/2013'

Comment: The risk with this solution is that you're doing a string compare instead of date compare.  So, you must be careful to match date formats.